# Code in the child route page getting executed before the promise callback in parent route page is executed in Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, promise, rxjs, es6-promise

I am having a pages component whose routing file pages.routing.ts has the following routing

```
  const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'pages',
    component: PagesComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'home', loadChildren: './home/home.module#HomeModule'}
    ]
  }
 ];
```

The code inside pages.component.ts file is

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.commonService.canAccess()
  .then(response => {
    if(response['data']) {
      sessionStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(response['data']));
      this.commonService.updateCurrentUserValue(response['data']);
    }
  },
    () => {
      // handle error here
    });
}
```

In the common service I have a 'currentUserSubject' which is a BehaviorSubject and I am exposing this value using a public getter so that I can access it from other components. The code in the common.service .ts file is

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {        
        this.currentUserSubject = new BehaviorSubject<string>(sessionStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
}

public get currentUserValue(): any {
    return JSON.parse(this.currentUserSubject.value);
}

public updateCurrentUserValue(currentUser: any) {
    this.currentUserSubject.next(JSON.stringify(currentUser));
}

async canAccess() {        
    return await this.http.request('GET', this.apiUrl, httpOptions)
        .pipe(
             map(response => {
                return response;
            }))
        .toPromise();
}
```

Now I am trying to use the currentUserValue in my home.component.ts file as shown below.

```
ngOnInit() {
  const currentUser = this.commonService.currentUserValue;
}
```

The problem is before code inside  the 'then' callback in the pages.component.ts file is executed, the code in the ngOnInit of home.component.ts file is executed and 'currentUser' in home component is null. How can I make the callback code in the pages.component.ts file get executed before the code in the home.component.ts? Please help me out with this

Answer (score 0):

It's simple make changes like this

in your common.service.ts file

```
public get currentUserValue(): any {
    return  this.currentUserSubject.asObservable();
 }
```

and in your home.component.ts file

```
 ngOnInit(){
     this.commonService.currentUserValue.subscribe(user => console.log(user));
  }
```

Comment: Hi. I tried this approach but still the code inside the subscribe in the home.component.ts is being executed before the code inside 'then' callback in the pages.component.ts and the user value inside subscribe is null